# Insert rows with previous row to keep column value continuously increase

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data which missed some value, I need insert fake row with previous row.

example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [1,'A'],
    [2,'B'],
    [3,'C'],
    [4,'D'],
    [5,'E'],
    [7,'G'],
    [9,'H'],
    [10,'I']
    ]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['v1','v2'])
                  
print(df)
```

This sample v1 column should be increasing, so #6 missing, I would like to insert  [6,'E'] to get final results.

Comment: And also insert 8?

Comment: yes, any not continuously gap need to be refilled, not only 1 missed

Comment: OK, have you tested the approach below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
out = (df.set_index('v1')
         .reindex(range(1, df['v1'].max()+1), method='ffill')
         .reset_index()
       )
```

Output:

```
   v1 v2
0   1  A
1   2  B
2   3  C
3   4  D
4   5  E
5   6  E
6   7  G
7   8  G
8   9  H
9  10  I
```

---

Alternatively, if you have several stretches of increasing values (e.g. 4->6, then 2->10), [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) the rows and increment the values with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
# identify the number of missing value between consecutive rows
# for this compute the diff, ignore negative values
n = df['v1'].diff(-1).mul(-1).fillna(1).clip(lower=1)
# or
# n = df['v1'].diff().shift(-1, fill_value=1).clip(lower=1)

# repeat the rows to add the missing values
out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(n)]
# increment the new rows
out['v1'] += out.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
```

Example (`*` denote the inserted rows):

```
   v1 v2
0   4  A     # stretch 1
0   5  A  *
1   6  B
2   2  C     # stretch 2
2   3  C  *
3   4  D
4   5  E
4   6  E  *
5   7  G
5   8  G  *
6   9  H
7  10  I
```

Alternative input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'v1': [4, 6, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10],
                   'v2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I']})
```

Comment: what does "grounby(level=0) mean? never saw such usage before :-)

Comment: This is to use the index as grouper, since we have repeated the rows, the repeated rows share the same index. Try to run `out.groupby(level=0).cumcount()` by itself to see the intermediate.

Comment: good, if I need decrease sequence, how should I change that line?

Comment: I guess use `-=` instead or `+=` ;) or for the first approach, use a reverse range with -1 as step. Provide an additional example if you need help.